# Insert short description after YITH Wishlist button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm using YITH WooCommerce Wishlist plugin and in my WooCommerce single product pages, I'm trying to insert the "Short description" block after the YITH Wishlist button.

My wishlist html element is:

```
<div class="yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist add-to-wishlist-48">
    label
    <div class="yith-wcwl-wishlistaddresponse"></div>
</div>
```

What is the tag to add action so that description goes after the element wish list?

My example code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_...','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt' );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible easily and instead of moving the short description, you can place this Wishlist button before the short description. You will have first to change in the General settings of [YITH WooCommerce Wishlist](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/) plugin, for "Position" you will choose "Use shortcode" and you will **save** that setting:

[image]

Then you will add a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** action hook with a priority of 15 *(between the product price (10) and the short description (20))*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist', 15 );
function custom_yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist(){
    echo do_shortcode('[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]');
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Related WooCommerce template: [**content-single-product.php**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/content-single-product.php)

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Snippet: Display YITH Wishlist Buttons @ Shop Page – WooCommerce  [YITH WooCommerce Wishlist](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/)  Add code in your theme fuctions.php file**

**Then create a page for example (whislist)  and [yith_wcwl_wishlist] paste short code there  and update page and then go to YITH Plugin Settings then Select Wishlist Page (page name wishlist which you created).**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_display_yith_wishlist_loop', 97 );

    function bbloomer_display_yith_wishlist_loop() {
    echo do_shortcode( "[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]" );
    }
```